# Django 2.1 NoReverseMatch error Using post method in Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-forms

**Url :**

```
re_path(r'^detail/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', ProblemDetail.as_view(), name='problem_detail'),
```

**View :**

```
class ProblemDetail(View):
    template_name='problem/problem_detail.html'
    form_class=AnswerForm

    def get(self,request,slug):
        context={'problem':Problem.objects.get(slug=slug),'form':self.form_class()}
        return render(request,self.template_name,context)

    def post(self,request,slug):
        bound_form=self.form_class(request.POST)
        obj=Problem.objects.get(slug=slug)
        real_answer=obj.answer
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            if bound_form.cleaned_data['answer'] == real_answer:
                return render(request,
                              'problem/Answerstatus.html', 
                              {'message':'Good Job !'})
        else:
            return render(request,
                          'problem/Answerstatus.html',
                          {'message':'Wrong ! Try Again  !'})
```

**Template :**

```
{% extends "problem/base_problem.html" %}

{% block content%}
<h2>{{problem.p_name}}</h2>
<h3>{{problem.difficulty}}</h3>
<p>{{problem.p_description}}</p>
<form  action= "{% url 'problem_detail' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" > Check </button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The above template is a rough idea for testing (Its not Final template,needs tons of changes, we know that.)

I get the following error :

```
Reverse for 'problem_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail/(?P<slug>\\w+)/$']
```

Comment: You are mixing create with detail. Your url needs an id to fetch an object, hence the detail, but your view is for creating an object kinda. Also ¿why not use DetailView and/or CreateView? It would be easier and less code.

Comment: The error means that you are not passing an argument in the url, but it requires it as you defined the pattern.

Comment: please add how you call the url named `problem_detail`.

Comment: I added the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add get_absolute_url method to your model like this :

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('problem_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

Also in your templates :

```
{% block body-block %}
<h2>{{problem.p_name}}</h2>
<h5>{{problem.difficulty}}</h5>
<p>{{problem.p_description}}</p>
<form  action= "{{ problem.get_absolute_url }}" method="post"> # Pay Attention here
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" > Check </button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This will fetch the url and the regex will match .

Answer (score 1):

You should add slug argument when you are returning in post method. Try returning HttpResponseRedirect and reverse to your url together with slug in args list.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('problem_detail', args=[slug]))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the problem is occuring in a `{% url %}` tag in your `problem/Answerstatus.html`, but we can't be sure because you haven't included that template in your question.

It looks as if you need to include the problem in your template whenever you render the template, for example,

```
return render(request, 'problem/Answerstatus.html', {'problem': obj, 'message':'Good Job !'})
```

and then in the template, include the slug in the `{% url %}` tag:

```
{% url 'problem_detail' problem.slug %}
```